# How to go to specific JSON node in dart

Tags: json, dart

I am kind of confused about how to get the specific node in dart. For example in this case, there are four ID inside. If I only want to get two ids in category, how should I get those information? Also, how should I start reading this file from Category in this case?

```
{
   "ID": "2",
   "BOOKSTORENAME": "bookstore name",
   "Category": {
      "ID": "1",
      "Book": [
         {
            "ID": "2",
            "Name": "book name 2"
         },
         {
            "ID": "3",
            "Name": "book name 3"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: "If I only want to get two ids in category". In you example there are only one ID in the "Category". Do you instead mean the two ID's in "Book"?

Comment: @julemand101 yeah that's what I mean. The ID of book name 2 and book name 3.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that a JSON is just a `Map<String, dynamic>` object for Dart. So, if your JSON was assigned to a variable `bookstores`, I would access a node like in this example:

```
// This would return a List<Map<String, String>> object
bookstores["Category"]["Book"]; 

// This should be true
bookstore == [
     {
        "ID": "2",
        "Name": "book name 2"
     },
     {
        "ID": "3",
        "Name": "book name 3"
     }
  ];
```

You just iterate through the nodes like that.

Comment: I see. So when I do not know how many data in JSON file (in this case is the number of book in each category and how many categories), I can get them in the List, right? And bookstores["Category"]["Book"] should return a List<Map<String, List>>?

Comment: Yes, you can get them from the list. However, I think that `bookstores["Category"]["Book"]` should return a `List<Map<String, String>>`, not a `List<Map<String, List>>` in this case, given the snippet you provided.